# Which type of training increases testosterone the most, focused on strength or muscle growth?

Tags: workout-routines, testosterone

And what kind of training should a person who has the natural testosterone increase as his main goal choose?

Comment: What do you believe that increasing your testosterone would accomplish? What are your current testosterone levels?

Comment: "While testosterone is definitely anabolic and promotes muscle growth in men and women at high doses, such as those used during steroid abuse, our findings show that naturally occurring levels of testosterone do not influence the rate of muscle protein synthesis." https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/06/120614130946.htm (In case you'd like to increase natural T in order to build muscles)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that "natural testosterone increase" is not your actual goal.  Rather you believe that more testosterone will help with something like muscle gain, hair growth, fat loss, psychological or sexual health,...  Making T level an intermediate goal at best.

### TLDR

I think that you should focus on your actual goals, whatever those may be.

Here's why:

1. "Normal" T levels for adult men is a pretty big range
2. The evidence that higher T levels within the normal range will change much is, at best, not convincing
3. Raising T levels is a complicated thing.  Intense exercise that uses large amounts of muscle can raise your T by 15%.  For about half an hour.  And then will lower your T level for a couple of days. (cites below)
4. There's not much evidence that either the raise or the lowering change much, in and of themselves

### More detail

"Normal" T levels for adult men is a pretty big range.  Bob could have 4 times as much as Fred, and they're both normal.  What's more, the T that they have is likely to have about the same effect on them since T is autoregulated by increased levels leading to decreased sensitivity.

Due to that autoregulation, there's some evidence that if you are within the normal range, additional T would have to be extreme to move the needle much.  If you are below the normal range, additional T does seem to make a difference, but in that case it seems that you will likely need exogenous T, because if your body isn't making enough in the first place, exercise isn't likely to bump you up by enough to notice.

People who are taking T without a doctor's supervision can easily have T ten times the high end of normal.  That *does* make a difference, but it's also not the sort of thing that any amount/type of exercise will ever get you.

Yes, every little bit helps, but as the first sentence of the Conclusion of [Testosterone Physiology in Resistance Exercise and Training](https://elementssystem.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Vingrenetal2010SportsMedicineTestosteronePhysiologypaper.pdf) states:

> As a hormone, circulating testosterone signalling resides within a multivariate system of anabolic signals for many different target tissues through the body, and the exact role of testosterone in the temporal timeframes of a resistance training programme are hard to pinpoint.

They then go on to use a lot of words to say you can't ignore it, but we're not sure what, why, or how, but we're pretty sure it does *something*.  Probably.

Focus on your actual goals.  Don't get hung up on how you get there.

### Cites

1. Hakkinen K, Pakarinen A. Acute hormonal responses totwo different fatiguing heavy-resistance protocols in maleathletes. J Appl Physiol 1993 Feb; 74 (2): 882-760
2. Koziris LP, Kraemer WJ, Gordon SE, et al. Effect of acutepostexercise ethanol intoxication on the neuroendocrine response to resistance exercise. J Appl Physiol 2000 Jan;88 (1): 165-72
3. [Testosterone Physiology in Resistance Exercise and Training](https://elementssystem.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Vingrenetal2010SportsMedicineTestosteronePhysiologypaper.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Testosterone is produced by your testicles and in normal levels it doesnt do any damage. Low level of testosterone could be a sign of a disfunctional testicle or a varicocele.Each body type has different levels of testosterone. People that are close to mesomorph body type has higher testosterone. You can keep your testosterone levels high enough for your body type by reducing the sugar you receive. Sugar can reduce testosterone 25%.

Training the big muscles of your body like glutes, quads, chest and back will help keeping your testosterone high. Using full body exercises like the deadlift or the Olympic lifting movements is proven that will help you reach the maximum testosterone levels that your body can produce naturally.

The time of the day is also important. Researches have shown that we have higher level of testosterone in the morning after a 7-8 hours of sleep.

Alcohol and smoking are testosterone killers.

It is proven that a correct posture matters a lot in the testosterone production system.

Answer (score -3):

I think to increase testosterone leg workout plays a major role. So don't ever skip leg day if you want to gain muscle and in leg workout squats, lunges and leg press are very important exercises.

Comment: Welcome to Fitness.SE! Can you elaborate more on why leg workouts play a role in increasing testosterone? Potentially, add a source as well.

Comment: You can refer to this page for more information: https://www.menshealth.com/uk/workouts/g753898/testosterone-boosting-leg-day-workout/

Comment: The purpose of this board, as I understand it, is to provide information which is higher quality than the typical website.    In other words, we try to reference actual scientific studies here.   I looked up the menshealth article, and they mention the journal of strength and conditioning, but they don't provide a citation.  It is impossible to know what study they are referring to.  I would challenge @Hemant to dive into the research literature and come back with some actual citations.

Comment: Probably this publication: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24276305/